# What is "うち" in "ごろうち"?

Tags: grammar, words

I recently came across this sentence:

> たかしは7時ごろうちに帰りました。

I do understand that it probably means たかし came home at around 7, but from what I learnt to say "around 7" it's:

> ７時ごろ.

So it has no うち.  In other words, the うち is throwing me off.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Do we have to use romaji in our answers?

Comment: No. I just used it so I wouldn't have to switch between languages.

Comment: I think your *uchi* here (内) means "home" in this case and not "around" . . .

Comment: @Robusto we should clarify that the kanji in that case would be 家 and not 内

Comment: @ssb: "Home" is [another reading of 内](http://kanjidict.stc.cx/4662). But since the OP used romaji, it's not clear anyway. But if I were to hear that sentence, I would infer that home was meant, and not a double dose of "around" . . .

Comment: The NHK漢字表記辞典 says it *would* be 家 in kanji, but it says うち in this sense should actually be written in kana instead--it's not included on the 常用漢字表 as an official reading for 家.  As an aside, I couldn't find any examples of 内に帰る in [BCCWJ](http://www.kotonoha.gr.jp/shonagon/) that used 内 to write うち, so even unofficially it's probably not usually written that way.

Comment: It would have to be 家. 「内に帰る」 sounds so philosophical and profound IF anyone ever said it. It sure is not something you do around 7 o'clock anyway.

Comment: @Tokyo: Haha, good point. I'd be satisfied with snailplane's explanation anyway.

Answer (score 4):

If you had the original kanji, it'd be more clear, but as Robusto [mentioned in the comments](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14044/what-is-uchi-in-goro-uchi#comment30246_14044), the うち in your sentence likely refers to "home" instead of "around".